# Working with flash with Mercurial: how to handle the FLA?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, version-control, mercurial, flash-cs5

How do teams do to work all at the same time on the same `.fla` file when working with version control?

We are a team of 2 working on a flash game right now and we found that, since it is a binary file, we can't work on the `.fla` file at the same time or one or the other will need to replace his file (because it's almost impossible to merge).

The best solution we could find for short term, is texting the other "lock" and "unlock" whenever we want to work on the file. Yes, it is very inconvenient, I agree. There *has* to be a clean solution to this.

So how do big teams manage a binary file with version control?

What would be our alternative?

*We use flash cs5 along with bitbucket and TurtoiseHg, if that changes anything.*

Thank you for your precious time.

Comment: The usual generic advice is to avoid versioning binary files, and instead version mergeable text files which can be used to generate them. Is there any way to do that with Flash?

Comment: Interesting, but I truly don't know. I might find a solution by searching more into that direction. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

refer a following site:

[Flash CS5 and Version Control](http://www.dz015.com/?p=202)

Comment: I took a look at that link before but it was unsuccessful for us. It also ends with the line "Unfortunately this means that we are effectively in exactly the same situation as we were with version control and FLA files.", so we understood that this was out of possibility. Did you find a way to make it work?